# Changing colorspaces with numpy.tensordot

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image I've read from file with shape `(m,n,3)` (i.e. it has 3 channels). I also have a matrix to convert the color space with dimensions `(3,3)`. I've already arrived at a few different ways of applying this matrix to each vector in the image; for example,

```
np.einsum('ij,...j',transform,image)
```

appears to make for the same results as the following (far slower) implementation.

```
def convert(im: np.array, transform: np.array) -> np.array:
    """ Convert an image array to another colorspace """
    dimensions = len(im.shape)
    axes = im.shape[:dimensions-1]

    # Create a new array (respecting mutability)
    new_ = np.empty(im.shape)

    for coordinate in np.ndindex(axes):
        pixel            = im[coordinate]
        pixel_prime      = transform @ pixel
        new_[coordinate] = pixel_prime

    return new_
```

However, I found that the following is even more efficient while testing on the example image with [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler).

```
np.moveaxis(np.tensordot(transform, X, axes=((-1),(-1))), 0, 2)
```

The problem I'm having here is using *just* a `np.tensordot`, i.e. removing the need for `np.moveaxis`. I've spent a few hours attempting to find a solution (I'm guessing it resides in choosing the correct `axes`), so I thought I'd ask others for help.

Comment: Did you try `image@transform.T`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I did not, but that appears to be even simpler (and just about as fast as using `np.tensordot`). Thank you for suggesting it.

Comment: You can get better performance from `einsum` by using the argument `optimize=True`.  (Requires numpy 1.12 or later.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks! That appears to make it about as fast as the other methods here now. I was not aware of that optional argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it concisely with `tensordot` if you make `image` the first argument:

```
np.tensordot(image, transform, axes=(-1, 1))
```

You can get better performance from `einsum` by using the argument `optimize=True` (requires numpy 1.12 or later):

```
np.einsum('ij,...j', transform, image, optimize=True)
```

Or (as Paul Panzer pointed out in a comment), you can simply use matrix multiplication:

```
image @ transform.T
```

They all take about the same time on my computer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this does indeed appear to be correct. Now I'm curious as to why the former appears to give on average a better performance by about 0.007s, or ~16%. This is marginal, of course, but I would have expected one less function call to reduce the time even further.

Comment: What is the actual shape of `image`?  (I.e. what are `m` and `n`?)

Comment: The image I'm using is `1280x1014` pixels.